# Java Convert MouseEvent to ActionEvent

Tags: java, mouseevent

is it possible to convert a MouseEvent to an ActionEvent?

Comment: Why? What are you attempting to do? I'm sure there is a better solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not without losing some information. The `MouseEvent` contains information about the mouse location (`x, y`) and which buttons that are pressed (if any).

---

I would do the conversion like this:

```
MouseEvent me = ...;
ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(me.getSource(), me.getID(), me.paramString());
```

Comment: Thanks! Useful answer if you have keystroke action and also want to fire it from some mouse action like mouse wheel action

Answer (score 3):

Sure, that's what a Button does (to my understanding). It processes a `MouseEvent` and creates (sends) an `ActionEvent`.

Action events are semantic events - like a signal, that a certain button (widget!) has been "pressed". The trigger for this action event may have been a mouse event ("left button has been pressed and released while the mouse pointer was in the rectangle defined by a AWT Button widget") or a keyboard event ("Space bar has been pressed and released while the focus was at AWT Button widget").

I guess you're not looking at a technical conversion. Practiacally, you'll have to listen to mouse events and fire new action events to your action listeners.